# pass string with spaces into javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to pass a php defined string with spaces to a javascript function, so that i can append to a query string.  However, the function only works when there are NO spaces, and does not even execute when there are spaces -- by testing with alert().

is there a way I can pass strings with spaces into javascript functions, so that i can eventually do an escape(), and then append to my query string? (using alert() in this example)

**.php file**

```
<a onClick=showUser('<?php echo $stringwithspaces; ?>')>click here</a>
```

**.js file**

```
function showUser(str)
{
alert (str);
}
```

if I could only do something like... `onClick=showUser(escape('<?php echo $deptname; ?>'))`... that would be awesome, but that didn't work.  Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: I don’t think the full contents of your PHP file have made it into the question. Could you edit it to get them in there?

Comment: You need to write valid HTML before anything else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you didn't quote the [attribute value](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2). You can leave quotes off of attribute values only if the value doesn't contain spaces, otherwise the HTML processor can't tell when an attribute ends. Even so, it's not recommended; you should always quote HTML attributes.

```
<a href="showUser('<?php echo addslashes($username) ?>')">user</a>
```

should work. The call to [`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes) escapes quotes, which would otherwise cause another problem (ending the attribute or string argument of `showUser` too soon).

Comment: Thank you a million! i can't believe how much time i spent trying to fix that error... very good lesson learned.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can you are missing **"** in you xml attribute field:
Each attribute must have a starting and an ending **"**

`myField=`**"**`blabla  ...`**"**

```
onClick="showUser(escape('<?php echo $deptname; ?>'))"
```

Comment: What you're saying is *technically* incorrect, even though it's relevant to the problem here, since quotation marks aren't required for HTML attributes, only XHTML and XML attributes.  Without the quotes any value without a space in it would parse correctly.

Comment: You re right but i think it will be better to start with good habits and quote each attribute :)

Answer (score -1):

Try the Unicode escape sequence for a space character, '\u0020'.