# javascript alert php string with space

Tags: javascript, php, string, alert

how to get a php values contain spaces with javascript?
I have a php code below

```
<?php 
    $firstName = "my first name";
    echo "<input type='button' onclick=showFirstName(".$firstName.");>";
?>
```

and my script below

```
<script>
    function showFirstName(firstName){
    alert(firstName);
}
</script>
```

and that alert wont work, it is different if just like `$firstName = "My"`.
anyone have solution?
Thankyou :)

Comment: wrap in quotes - `...onclick=showFirstName('".$firstName."');>";`

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass string with spaces into javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939764/pass-string-with-spaces-into-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php 
    $firstName = "my first name";
    echo "<input type='button' onclick='showFirstName(\"".addslashes($firstName)."\")'>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `'`s properly. Try with -

```
echo "<input type='button' onclick=showFirstName('".$firstName."');>";
```

Comment: Beat me to it, but yeah, missing single quotes so it's trying to do: showFirstName(my first name); - which won't work as "my first name" is not inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put single quotes when call `showFirstName` method

```
<?php 
    $firstName = "my first name";
    echo "<input type='button' onclick=showFirstName('".$firstName."');>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put onclick function calling in double quotes like this:

```
$firstName = "my first name";
echo "<input type='button' onclick=\"showFirstName('$firstName');\">";
```

Comment: thankyou @Sanjay this work form me, I'm just missing the `\" \"` in the `onclick` function